# In Mac systems, where is located the texmaker.ini file?

Tags: texmaker

I'm looking for the `texmaker.ini` file inside my MacBook with OS 10.11.
Someone could provide information about the position of the file.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014, http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-using-the-find-command-1305633

Comment: @Marijn I already tried both!

Comment: in the terminal you could try `cd / ` to go to the root of the filesystem and retry the `find . -name "texmaker.ini"` from there, possibly `sudo find . -name "texmaker.ini"` if you have sudo (administrator) rights to prevent access denied errors. If it is not found from the root then the file does not exist.

Comment: I wanted to write a similar comment. Although you should, especially when using privileges, limit the search scope. with -x i.e. "sudo find -x . -name "texmaker.ini"" because else you are going to search wherever the filesystems leads.

Comment: I tried all the possibilities you (@Marijn and @eject) have suggested but the result provide no file called `texmaker.ini`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `texmaker.ini` file is created in the user's home and it's stored in

```
~/.config/xm1
```

If I do

```
ls ~/.config/xm1/
```

the result is

```
texmaker.ini        texmakerapp.ini
```

The second file contains just the initialization for the language interface. The start of the first file is

```
[General]
IniMode=true

[texmaker]
Beamer\Author=
Beamer\BabelDefault=english
Beamer\Encoding=utf8
Beamer\Size=11pt
Beamer\Theme=Warsaw
Color\Background=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\0\0)
Color\Command=@Variant(\0\0\0\x43\x1\xff\xff\x80\x80\0\0\0\0\0\0)
```

Please, make certain you have write privileges in the `~/.config` directory; as [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30941/discussion-between-mattia-and-egreg), the result of `ls -ld ~/.config` should output something like

```
drwx------  11 foouser  staff  374 Oct 31 15:34 /Users/foouser/.config/
```

where `foouser` stands for your user name. If it's `root`, this means the directory has been created by some application under a `sudo` regime. Just issue

```
sudo chown foouser ~/.config
```

(`foouser` should be what you see as output of `whoami`) and then

```
chmod go-rx ~/.config
```

Check the output of `ls -ld ~/.config` and, in case, issue the suitable `chmod` command,

```
chmod u+rwx ~/.config
```

This should solve all your issues, because now Texmaker will be able to save the `.ini` files in the proper place.

Comment: Hi egreg, thanks for your support. I checked, but in my `~/.config` folder there is no `/xm1` directory.

Comment: @Mattia What version of Texmaker?

Comment: Texmaker 4.4.1 it should be the last released (I reinstall MacTeX (TexLive 2015) and Texmaker after the update to El Capitan).

Comment: @Mattia I don't know with OS X 10.11, but with 10.9, upon moving away the `~/.config/xm1` directory, launching Texmaker and quitting it recreates the directory. Anyway, the latest release is 4.5.

Comment: Ok, probably this is related to some changes in paths due to the new OS. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mattia Do you see anything in `~/.config`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30941/discussion-between-mattia-and-egreg).